# Does HTML Encoding a mailto tag stop spammers

Tags: html, email-spam

I think its fairly common practice these days not to include a mailto: tag in your webpage.  I also realize that a better solution is to have a contact us form.

Recently I've seen some mailto tags that include and HTML encoded email address.  Is this an effective way to stop spammers from attacking an email address?

Example:

```
<a href="mailto:&#110;&#101;&#119;&#098;&#105;...">email me</a>
```

Also, are there any other techniques that I've left out?  Which is the best method?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483212/effective-method-to-hide-email-from-spam-bots maybe you'll find something helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've heard, it will help reduce the influx of spam but will not stop it entirely. A minority (for now) of email-address-harvesting bots are smart enough to apply the decoding.

Comment: Added a second part to my question.  What's ideal?  any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Another technique is to use some Javascript to dynamically generate the mailto tag at page load time. In order for spammers to scrape such addresses, they would need to have a full Javascript processor in their web spider.

Some spammers may already do this.

Comment: But in order for users to contact your business, they must have javascript enabled - not everyone does!

Answer (score 1):

For my personal home page, I give the email address in a graphic.  Then I apologize for not making it a link.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use the [Hivelogic Enkoder](http://hivelogic.com/enkoder).  It is helpful for encoding an entire link element, not just the mailto.

One lesson learned the annoying way, however, is to comment your code with what the original element looked like *before* encoding. I've accidentally left off classes on the `<a>` tag a few times.

Answer (score 1):

Without making it hard for some of your users, you're only ever going to be able to stop lazy spammers — because you don't know ahead of time which you're looking at. So if you deliver something easily accessible to a legitimate user, you're delivering something easily accessible to a spammer.

My best advice is just to get a very good spam filter if you're going to put your address on the Web. No amount of href obfuscation will do as much good.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd encourage using a form as that will give you much greater control over how you tackle any potential spam. (Personally I don't like "front end" solutions such as CAPTCHA as they're rarely user friendly - if it causes any inconvenience/additional work for your user, I generally like to see if there's a better way)

Using a form also has the additional benefit of enabling you to obtain data from the contactee with some kind of structure. (I.e. it reduces the risk of someone contacting you with a question, but not providing enough info (even their name perhaps) which might help you in providing them with the best response possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using simple Javascript string concatenation and substring operations to obfuscate the email address for years on several websites. This seems to have worked well, since I got minimal spam on these addresses. This cannot mean that it will still work in the future.