# How to hide the email address in the view source of ASP.Net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

The Acunetix Web Vulnerability tool reports that there are pages in our web application that exposes email addresses of our clients. This is so because the client profile web form requires email address to be encoded. When editing the profile though, the email address is then exposed in the view source which is a window for spamming. Is it possible to hide the email address in the view source but still be viewable and accessible in the client form? I am using c#.net 2010 asp.net.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I Think the question you must ask yourself is, is this a page everyone can see or just the person that is the owner of the email address?
If so i don't this it's a big problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Effective method to hide email from spam bots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483212/effective-method-to-hide-email-from-spam-bots)

Comment: do not store clear email in the html code. Build your addresses with a js function, or even generate small images for each email.

Comment: Hi all! The email address is saved in a database then displayed and edited using textbox control. Bots crawl the web pages and get the email address and use it for spamming by the bot owner. That's why acunetix web tool reports it as a potential window for hacking or spamming. That said, we want to have a method to avoid exposing the email address so bots won't be able to read it.