# How to include email link in html tag so that when user clicks it, their email program loads up

Tags: html, email, outlook, href

Lets say there is this link:

```
<a href="someemaillink@somedomain.com">someemaillink@somedomain.coml</a>
```

And when user clicks the link above, their email client pops open.  How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML has a syntax for this:

```
<a href="mailto:joe@example.com?subject=feedback" "email me">email me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mailto:`

```
<a href="mailto:someemaillink@somedomain.com">someemaillink@somedomain.coml</a>
```

But consider using a [method that will not allow the address to be read by bots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483212/effective-method-to-hide-email-from-spam-bots) to send spam to. That is, if your usage is public.

Answer (score 1):

use this, this will work

```
<a href="mailto:someemaillink@somedomain.com">someemaillink@somedomain.coml</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, i found it:

```
<a href="mailto:someemaillink@somedomain.com">someemaillink@somedomain.coml</a>
```