# Using form to send email, but want to display the address yet remain protected from spambots

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, email

I've read many of the suggestions from this question ([Effective method to hide email from spam bots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483212/effective-method-to-hide-email-from-spam-bots)), but my need is slightly different.

I have a WordPress site and a very good forms plug-in.  For email links, the `<a href>` will load a basic contact form in a lightbox.  It works perfectly.
But...  I've been asked to display the email address for the two following reasons:

1. People who like to copy/paste or write down addresses can do so without having to submit a form
2. Accessibility.  I'd like site readers to be able to verbalise the email address

Short of using an image which is a screenshot of the email address, how can I display the address yet remain protected from spam-bots?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no way to 100% protect yourself from spam and allow people a clickable link. There are ways to lower the change. Some use javascript to write the email address in parts href="javascript:print('email');print('@test.com')"

Comment: Why don't you add a button which will show the email address? like `<button onclick="showMail()">Show email address</button>` so spam-bots are not able to get your mail. the most spam bots will look for this pattern: `/^(?:([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(?:\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(?:".+"))@(?:([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(?:\.))+([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,}))$/` so you can write mail(at)example.com