# Email Masking in wordpress widget

Tags: wordpress, email-spam

I have a wordpress website in which we have used widgets and we have added html mail  like this

```
<a href="mailto: myemail.examlple.com"> my email </a>
```

**I want to protect this email id from spams when user did view source.**

I already disabled copy paste.
Any idea?

Comment: Use an ROT13 cipher.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Effective method to hide email from spam bots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483212/effective-method-to-hide-email-from-spam-bots)

Answer (score 1):

### Quoted Fuhrmanator ([Effective method to hide email from spam bots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483212/effective-method-to-hide-email-from-spam-bots))

This is the method I used, with a server-side include, e.g. `<!--#include file="emailObfuscator.include" -->` where `emailObfuscator.include` contains the following:

```
<!-- // http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20040202/154813.html -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gen_mail_to_link(lhs,rhs,subject) {
        document.write("<a href=\"mailto");
        document.write(":" + lhs + "@");
        document.write(rhs + "?subject=" + subject + "\">" + lhs + "@" + rhs + "<\/a>");
    }
</script>
```

To include an address, I use JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    gen_mail_to_link('john.doe','example.com','Feedback about your site...');
</script>
<noscript>
  <em>Email address protected by JavaScript. Activate JavaScript to see the email.</em>
</noscript>
```

Because I have been getting email via Gmail since 2005, spam is pretty much a non-issue. So, I can't speak of how effective this method is. You might want to read [this study](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/) (although it's old) that produced this graph:

[image]